# Looking to Loop Excel VBA Macro through Multiple Worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel

Looking to loop the following code through (about) 125 worksheets in an Excel workbook and pull the listed cell values into one database entry log on the 'Database' worksheet'.  Right now it is only pulling from one of the tabs . (PO VT-0189).  Wondering how to correct.

```
Private Sub PopulateOrderInfo()
    Dim OrderDate As String, PONumber As String, Vendor As String, ShipTo As String, SKU As String
    Dim R As Long, LastSKURow As Long, NextDBRow As Long, OFrm As Worksheet, DB As Worksheet
    For Each OFrm In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set OFrm = Worksheets("PO VT-0189")
        Set DB = Worksheets("Database")
        OrderDate = OFrm.Range("N4")
        PONumber = OFrm.Range("N3")
        Vendor = OFrm.Range("A13")
        ShipTo = OFrm.Range("I13")
        POTotal = OFrm.Range("P43")
        LastSKURow = OFrm.Range("A38").End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 21 To LastSKURow
            SKU = OFrm.Range("A" & R).Value
            SKUDesc = OFrm.Range("D" & R).Value
            SKUQty = OFrm.Range("K" & R).Value
            Lntotal = OFrm.Range("M" & R).Value
            NextDBRow = DB.Cells(DB.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            DB.Range("A" & NextDBRow).Value = OrderDate
            DB.Range("B" & NextDBRow).Value = PONumber
            DB.Range("C" & NextDBRow).Value = Vendor
            DB.Range("D" & NextDBRow).Value = ShipTo
            DB.Range("E" & NextDBRow).Value = SKU
            DB.Range("F" & NextDBRow).Value = SKUDesc
            DB.Range("G" & NextDBRow).Value = SKUQty
            DB.Range("H" & NextDBRow).Value = Lntotal
            DB.Range("I" & NextDBRow).Value = POTotal
        Next R
    Next OFrm
End Sub
```

Comment: Because of this line `Set OFrm = Worksheets("PO VT-0189")`!

Comment: As @SJR said. Your `For Each OFrm....` line sets a reference to each sheet as it goes through the loop (much the same as a `For...Next` loop).  You then ignore that allocation and reset it _PO VT-0189_ in the line SJR mentions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also shorten your code by avoiding the loop and most of the variables seem unnecessary to me.

```
Private Sub PopulateOrderInfo()

Dim R As Long, LastSKURow As Long, NextDBRow As Long, OFrm As Worksheet, DB As Worksheet

Set DB = Worksheets("Database")

For Each OFrm In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If OFrm.Name <> DB.Name Then
        LastSKURow = OFrm.Range("A38").End(xlUp).Row
        R = LastSKURow - 21 + 1
        NextDBRow = DB.Cells(DB.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        DB.Range("A" & NextDBRow).Resize(R).Value = OFrm.Range("N4")
        DB.Range("B" & NextDBRow).Resize(R).Value = OFrm.Range("N3")
        DB.Range("C" & NextDBRow).Resize(R).Value = OFrm.Range("A13")
        DB.Range("D" & NextDBRow).Resize(R).Value = OFrm.Range("I13")
        DB.Range("E" & NextDBRow).Resize(R).Value = OFrm.Range("A21").Resize(R).Value
        DB.Range("F" & NextDBRow).Resize(R).Value = OFrm.Range("D21").Resize(R).Value
        DB.Range("G" & NextDBRow).Resize(R).Value = OFrm.Range("K21").Resize(R).Value
        DB.Range("H" & NextDBRow).Resize(R).Value = OFrm.Range("M21").Resize(R).Value
        DB.Range("I" & NextDBRow).Resize(R).Value = OFrm.Range("P43")
    End If
Next OFrm

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting a run-time error (1004) . stating that application-defined or object-defined error currently.

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: If OFrm.Name <> DB.Name Then

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and WorkSheets collection like:

```
For I = 1 to worksheets.count
 if worksheets(i).name <> "Database" then 
  Add your code here
 end if
Next i
```

This loops through every worksheet in your workbook and does what ever you need to all worksheets except the Database.

Comment: Was going to vote down for the use of a `For....Next` when trying to step through a collection (`For....Each` loops through each item in a collection), but decided not to as I guess it works and you are excluding the Database sheet.... `For...Each` is preferred though.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for each...` loop

```
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets 
     If ws.name = "Database" Then   
'Leave blank to just skip database. Code here if you want something special on database. OR statements can be used to exclude additional sheets
 Else 
'Code here  
 End If  
    Next
```

Comment: Couldn't you do if ws.name <> "Database" then and not have a need for the else?

Comment: Yes - I have a style preference towards writing my if's like this, as well as always including the if. It makes it blindingly obvious what I'm doing/trying to do, and allows for easy editing/changing/stealing

Answer (score 0):

I think you described the issue fairly well.  Just to confirm, you want to loop through all worksheets in one single workbook, right.  Try the script below.  Feedback if you have additional questions, concerns, etc.  Thanks.

```
Sub ImportAll()

Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean, blnEXCEL As Boolean, blnReadOnly As Boolean
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim objExcel As Object, objWorkbook As Object
Dim colWorksheets As Collection
Dim strPathFile as String, strTable as String
Dim strPassword As String

' Establish an EXCEL application object
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      blnEXCEL = True
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\Filename.xls with the actual path and filename
strPathFile = "C:\Filename.xls"

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
' the data are to be imported
strTable = "tablename"

' Replace passwordtext with the real password;
' if there is no password, replace it with vbNullString constant
' (e.g., strPassword = vbNullString)
strPassword = "passwordtext"

blnReadOnly = True ' open EXCEL file in read-only mode

' Open the EXCEL file and read the worksheet names into a collection
Set colWorksheets = New Collection
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPathFile, , blnReadOnly, , _
      strPassword)
For lngCount = 1 To objWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
      colWorksheets.Add objWorkbook.Worksheets(lngCount).Name
Next lngCount

' Close the EXCEL file without saving the file, and clean up the EXCEL objects
objWorkbook.Close False
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
If blnEXCEL = True Then objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing

' Import the data from each worksheet into the table
For lngCount = colWorksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, colWorksheets(lngCount) & "$"
Next lngCount

' Delete the collection
Set colWorksheets = Nothing

' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
' EXCEL file after it's been imported
' Kill strPathFile

End Sub
```